# How to load theme from external file to application in iPhone (objective-c)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, themes, dynamic-library

I have some question about objective-c and theming.
I know there are many topics about themes but I didn't find answer for my question.

So I will (it is under construction :)) have an iPhone application and I would like to have possibility to make skins and share it in AppStore.
The problem is how to "join" new images to my application (from downloaded file). I don't want to keep it on "disk" in native format (for example .jpg).
I thought about dynamic library - but is it good idea to make library with images only? And how dynamically link library with application?

Note that it is not interesting for me how to switch themes in application (I know how to do this) but only how to link new theme images from other external file.

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do something with themes is to write a library that "draws" the images for you! Download an xml file with all the color codes in it and let the library fill in the images, colors, text settings and draw the gradients. That is the most dynamically efficient way to use theme's on a phone.

And if you don't want to store the images locally on the phone why don't you asynchronously download them during startup? It doesn't seem like a very good idea but it's an option. I'd prefer to have the images locally on my phone. So when I download a new theme the images are downloaded too and the old theme is removed.

Comment: Yeah, it's good idea, but I don't want to keep images locally to prevent user modify it and create his own skins for free - this is main assumption (that's not my idea, application is not for me).

But I don't have any idea, so probably I do it as you said. :)